# sql server showing invaild object name thouh having table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Getting invalid object name <table_name> while selecting the table name, since it is connecting

`select * from user.tablename` giving output

`select * from tablename` not giving output

since connectd database as well

use dbname

please help me out here

is this any grant related issue, im using sql serevr express edition

Comment: `select * from user.tablename` will error, `USER` is a reserved keyword. Though the solution is simple; always schema qualify your objects in T-SQL. `select * from tablename` doesn't schema qualify `tablename`, so just don't use it.

Comment: simple solution : don't have a schema named 'user', and always qualify table names with their respective schema

Answer (score -1):

give dbo permissions to replace the user.table_name

ALTER SCHEMA dbo transfer USER.TABLE_NAME

AND to get all this ,run below query

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER ' + s.Name + '.' + o.Name
FROM sys.Objects o
INNER JOIN sys.Schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE s.Name = 'compmsauser'
And (o.Type = 'U' Or o.Type = 'P' Or o.Type = 'V')
```